# POS Tagger issue for Singular and Plural Nouns

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp, pos-tagger, postageapp

input text : i always like hot Eggs
output
[('i', 'NN'), ('always', 'RB'), ('like', 'IN'), ('hot', 'JJ'), ('Eggs', 'NNP')]

according to PTB postag **NNP** is singular but why in this case its giving **NNP** why not **NNS**

Answer (score 1):

It's the upper-case initial that misguides the POS tagger to fail. Change it to *eggs* and you will get NNS.

Comment: you are 100% right , but point is that do i need to convert whole data set to to lower ? .so if it find someones name it will also make it NNS , what u think ?

Comment: no you shouldn't convert the data. You just need to accept the fact that data is not clean and POS tags are not always correct.

Comment: amazing , but can you help me or give me hint how i can clean this . seriously i got your point its amazing

Comment: search for true-caser in Machine Translation (MT). There must be some scripts. From the memory: there is a true-caser in Moses MT pipeline that you can train on large amount of clean text. It will learn the correct upper-case/lower-case variation of words and converts the test data into whatever that it learned in the training. So probably (not sure) that will change your Eggs to eggs and will keep proper nouns as proper nouns (i.e. as Upper-case initials). Note that it can backfire terribly if you train it on a messy or insufficient text - this is why I didn't recommend it...